# How to expand std::uses_allocator_construction_args into constructor parameter list?

Tags: c++, templates, allocator

I want to create a class `Entity` that can be templated for owning and non-owning string types (e.g. `std::string` or `std::string_view`). In both cases though there is internal datastructure to be allocated (vector) which needs an allocator, however in the string case I want to use the same allocator for the internal data structure as the string and have the `Entity` constructor forward this allocator to the string object. In the string_view case, the constructor of string_view doesn't take an allocator, so I would have to specialize the call to the constructor to NOT forward the allocator but initialize empty. I can get close with `uses_allocator_construction_args` but I can't unpack the tuple into the parameter list, what can I do instead?

Here's what I have and want to do:

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMxcpK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQgZv6kAA6oCoRODB7evgFBaRmOAmER0SxxCUm2mPbFDEIETMQEOT5%2BgTV1WY3NBKVRsfGJyQpNLW15nWN9A%2BWVIwCUtqhexMjsHOb%2B4cjeWADUJv5uTmPEmKzH2CYaAILbu/uYRycAbpgOJNe3D0lPXkOxzc53CwB%2B90eDD2gJewNBRgA%2Bm88JgAO4Qh73AiYFgpAw415uAgATxSjFYLzutFoqFERGImPOXgcBxR6MRTHQTBSOOIRwA7FZ7gdRQcvBkjAcEcBEaTya8ACLSgjoEAgGXI1EY/zCu5i8WS4AHMS0%2BkkOVkuH%2BZXUs1MBnHPUmAWKp2/X44vEE63Eq3MNgHRrEMEAFStTIIxBZBBVIaR8swiNQVGT/JdeoNErBB0TSqDUbDEd1Htd7sh2Nx%2BIdvsTAapNLpDu%2B/hu92ZrM1ieTqZbbnZaM53N58WBdqbjtb10FmbF2aleeOyoHQ55fLHjfNjNb6q7xedZZLFaxdy91cJwLrlIL8eA4fJkejrOwgkIJJnvyzRpNm%2BbxEtCpLjeRbkuqpoThaiblvqc7fnugE2nGYIAUmKZpsCwYgZg1zqlBR4ngaL6OKSEDgVuKE/vaDL5hmLqKosn4GmKIBsp8GaURB6ZliKTGiqQcbsRKmAKJyv4MoiaAMB29ScsQwAKBhhZGPe2GtqRYkkIsAB0OmCsqAD0%2BlEgAtKZxkHAAEqgaK5qgBxoiGhIEAgeAKf4ABijGirR3EEWKmHKVaAn4QaYxqiAHxfNubgBXeVqkF5TFXoGYVgRp/5RkwhBuW4ZF/ihOEgGePoHBcMThOgolmopt4qT8rasaY%2BF0dBHr3OEsYsFlDAQIsH48aKRFvvCqq7kp4INSwJLImI0GEa%2BpLAiuXJrqOJypSAeWTiCo0auNWrouqbxiF4SZ4TcU6TdNA6ta6HDLLQnAAKy8H4HBaKQqCcG41jWNKqzrHCSQ8KQBCaPdywANYgJIXBaQKACcAAcCOw4jKOw0j%2BicJIr3g59nC8AoIAaKD4PLHAsAwIgKCoHidDxOQlBoPT9AJPJzApAoCCoAQpBYCiGwAGragA8uSb0gzQtB8sTEAxPj5XMMQJKcCDSvNCSosxNonxg9wvAs2wgiiwwtCq%2B9vBYDEXjALlNLEwb/O4oYwDiJb/N4BcDh4B8jsfZgqifF4OL4x1tT47QeAxMQmseFg%2BOFiwav3XwBjySL6Li4wKcyIIIhiOwUh5/IShqPjuhBAYRgoL9lj6NHxOQMsqC8lkjvGWFS6mJY1hmBoBzGaLCi8KgHzECGWBN71XR61kLgMO4njtHooThIMFTDAU6SZAIkx%2BNvRRZHMQwJEEdhzwIvQTMveTn7Ul8NOM/Tr/MW%2B2M/%2B96DMLQn5vZ/LAUADDYEgHrPTxh7L6HADiqCRgANmMnAyQBxgDIGQAcCAUYvAMEhn1CAuBCAkCOMDRYvB9ZaEWFDEAT1SaPQ4LjUgycnqSC0pIBGiMNCIzYRwxGpA3ofSgUTEmZNLYU2phAJAqwCApBDkzCALMUgM2IJESknBYEIKQSgtBBwuD%2BC0iDTA%2BAGR4DVEEfg%2BdRDiGLuY0uKh1Ae0rqQByPIU5gI4C9Ph%2BMoGixDjI2MKYYHwMQcg1B6DMHRhwXgjwrN4jEMCKQkRFDlgIEuFgBIM86EMOTpIJ6WkaH9wRv3fJGhClBH4aPQmthhHkIhqQaGT0kZaX7lwDQDTmmtKRmYKunB/AQIEZUmplDsYcDMH0ipHAyHk2WOPDIzhJBAA%3D%3D%3D)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

template <typename Allocator>
struct view_adapter {
    using string_type = std::string_view;
    using allocator_type = Allocator;
};

template <typename StringType>
struct string_type_of_or {
    using type = StringType;
};

template <typename Allocator>
struct string_type_of_or<view_adapter<Allocator>> {
    using type = view_adapter<Allocator>::string_type;
};


template <typename StringType>
struct Entity {
    using allocator_type = StringType::allocator_type;
    using string_type = string_type_of_or<StringType>::type;

    Entity(allocator_type allocator = {})
        : vec{ allocator }
        , str{ uses_allocator_construction_args<StringType>(allocator)... } // <---- How to write this?
    {}

    StringType str;
    std::vector<StringType,
        typename std::allocator_traits<allocator_type>::template rebind_alloc<StringType>> vec;
};


int main() {
    Entity<std::string> my_val;
    Entity<view_adapter<std::allocator<std::string_view::value_type>>> my_view;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::make_obj_using_allocator<T>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/make_obj_using_allocator)

https://godbolt.org/z/sTffGn1ez:

```cpp
    Entity(allocator_type allocator = {})
        : vec{ allocator }
        , str( std::make_obj_using_allocator<string_type>(allocator) )
    {}
```

Comment: I'm wondering how I didn't consider using the copy constructor, since it is optimized out anyway.., thx!